# How do I work with array fields in Mongoid & Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, geolocation, mongoid

I have a place model that has two fields:

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, :type => String
  field :loc, :type => Array

  index([[:loc, Mongo::GEO2D]], :background => true)

  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

I can easily output lat and lon in my views with:

```
@place.loc['lat']
```

A record in MongoDB that represents each place looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "0293uhjf2hfio2h3" ),
  "name" : "Starbucks",
  "loc" : {
    "lat" : 44.106667,
    "lon" : -73.935833
  }
}
```

My question is how can I create a form that will allow me to edit or create new location (lat/lon) fields?

Comment: Just like any other form. Is there a problem?

Comment: If I create an input field with name place[loc][lat] then the update action of the controller returns an error: "Field was defined as a(n) Array, but received a ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess with the value". If I change the data type for loc to Hash, then nothing happens at all, even when I try to change the name field. Controller does say that the place was successfully updated though, even though it wasn't.

Comment: After digging for longer, I found out that update_attributes doesn't really update attributes, even though there _are_ new attributes. If I change values by hand and call place.save it works. But it's a very poor solution... So, I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of setting a field in the place model, I created another model called "loc" and added "embeds_one :loc" in place. So the place model looks like this now:

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name

  index([[:loc, Mongo::GEO2D]], :background => true)

  embeds_one :loc
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

And the loc model looks like this now:

```
class Loc
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :lat, :type => Integer
  field :lon, :type => Integer

  embedded_in :place
end
```

So, now I can have input fields in my form for location:

```
<input type="text" name="place[loc][lat]" id="place_loc_lat">
```